# 5V power supply that accepts wires? (terminal block?)

Tags: power-supply, usb-c

I recently removed my Vivint SkyControl panel from my wall, and there's already a wire running from the outlet in my utility room to the dining room. I was hoping to use that wire as a charger for a tablet that stays on the wall to control various smart home devices.

I was hoping to use [this cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B096RQNN8C) to change the wires to a USB-C cable, but the tablet is rated to take 9W or 15W, and the security system power supply puts out 30W (yikes! )

The installer had a plug that just took in wires, but I'm having trouble finding a variant of it that puts out less wattage. Does this type of power supply exist for 5V?

Comment: "the security system power supply puts out 30W (yikes! )" If it's outputting the right voltage for your load, and its *maximum* power output is 30W, this is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: `security system power supply puts out 30W (yikes! )` ... the AC power coming into your house can probably supply thousands of watts,  how come all of your appliances are not blowing up?